# Regression on Rescan for Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I implement a new plan tree Node for my Postgres, and I implement a Rescan function for it for ExecReScan in "execAmi.c" to call.

However, my coverage test shows that this function is not called in my regress tests. I doubt if i can include it in a regression test? When will the ExecRescan be called? I read its description, and it tells me that it "Reset a plan node so that its output can be re-scanned."; however, when will it be needed?

I tried to use ctrl+c in psql when querying, but the related codes are still not called.

I've read https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/custom-scan-execution.html#CUSTOM-SCAN-EXECUTION-CALLBACKS, which says it "Rewind the current scan to the beginning and prepare to rescan the relation.", but when would this function called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens in several places, for example during a nested loop join.

See `ExecNestLoop` in `src/backend/executor/nodeNestloop.c`:

```c
for (;;)
{
    /*
     * If we don't have an outer tuple, get the next one and reset the
     * inner scan.
     */
    if (node->nl_NeedNewOuter)
    {
        ENL1_printf("getting new outer tuple");
        outerTupleSlot = ExecProcNode(outerPlan);

        /*
         * if there are no more outer tuples, then the join is complete..
         */
        if (TupIsNull(outerTupleSlot))
        {
            ENL1_printf("no outer tuple, ending join");
            return NULL;
        }

        [...]

        /*
         * now rescan the inner plan
         */
        ENL1_printf("rescanning inner plan");
        ExecReScan(innerPlan);
    }

    /*
     * we have an outerTuple, try to get the next inner tuple.
     */

    [...]
}
```

So try to come up with a query where your custom node is on the inner side of a nested loop join.